# Prove that $\lim cf(x) = c\lim f(x)$

Tags: calculus

Well, I'm having trouble with these types of proofs, based on épsilon delta. I've found these proofs: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Calculus/Proofs_of_Some_Basic_Limit_Rules but I cannot understand. Can somebody explain the scalar product limit proof intuitively?

thank you so much

Comment: Well ... intuitively, it's saying that if $f(x)$ approaches $L$ as $x$ approaches infinity, then $cf(x)$ will approach $cL$ as $x$ approaches infinity.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I explain the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ limit definition to my students:

We wish to explain the meaning of the statement $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=L$.  Suppose you are trying to force the function $f$ to take a value close to $L$.  That is, someone tells you that you must get $f(x)$ to be close to $L$, with only a little bit of error allowed (this "little bit of error" is the $\epsilon$).  Then if it is really true that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=L$, then you should be able to force $f(x)$ to be close to $L$ by first forcing $x$ to be close to $c$.  The question is how close does $x$ need to be to $c$?  That distance will be your $\delta$.

That is, if you can force $x$ to be within $\delta$ of $c$, that will force $f(x)$ to be within your allowed error of $\epsilon$ of $L$.

Thus the statement "$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=L$" may be translated as "We can force $f(x)$ to be as close as we like to $L$ by merely forcing $x$ to be sufficiently close to $c$.

Now an intuitive proof of the property you mentioned.  Suppose $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to c}f(x)$ holds.  Let us first show that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to c}5f(x)=5\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=5L$.  That is, I want to show that I can force $5f(x)$ to be as close to $5L$ as I like just by forcing $x$ to be sufficiently close to $c$.  Well suppose that I want $5f(x)$ to be within $\dfrac{1}{100}$ of $5L$.  I just make $x$ be close enough to $c$ to force $f(x)$ to be within $\dfrac{1}{500}$ of $L$.  That is, so that $|f(x)-L|<\frac{1}{500}$.  Now just multiply both sides of that inequality by $5$.  We get

$$
|5f(x)-5L|<\dfrac{5}{500}=\dfrac{1}{100}.
$$

The very inequality we wanted!  Now replace the $5$ with any $a$ and the $\frac{1}{100}$ by any $\epsilon>0$, and we are done.  (Note: when I said "make $x$ close enough to $c$", that "close enough" would be the $\delta$.)

Comment: I'm really trying to understand this but I think I need a graphic interpretation of this. I don't understand how does the $f(x)$ must be within $\frac{1}{500}$ of $L$. Would I be asking too much if you could draw me an graphic representation of this? Thank you SO MUCH.

Comment: @user108425 I can force $f(x)$ to be within $\frac{1}{500}$ of $L$ because I already know that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=L$.  I am afraid I cannot make a graphic representation of this, though I am sure there are some out there online.